# nested loop: number pattern

Tags: c++, for-loop

In C++, I want a number pattern below:

```
 1
 2 1
 3 2 1
 4 3 2 1
 5 4 3 2
 6 5 4 3 
 7 6 5 4
 8 7 6 5
 9 8 7 6
```

For line 1-4, I did this:

```
 for(size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for(size_t j = 0 ; j  < i+1;  j++) {
        cout<<j;
    }
    cout<<endl;
 }
```

To complete line 5 - 9, should I separate an above pattern with 2 for loop?, is there an idea (one that actually works)?
Please give me some suggestions since mine does not work.

Comment: Hint, you want to compare a value with 4, I'll let you figure out which one. Also loops do not have to start at index zero. Good luck!

Comment: These lines of code are not going to print what you want to print, so you should rephrase the question from `is there a better idea` to `is there an idea` (one that actually works).

Comment: @shuttle87, you mean, use for loop with if-else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic nested loop case, as you have, but with some minor mods. Let's look at the actual expected output:

```
1
2 1
3 2 1
4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2
6 5 4 3 
7 6 5 4
8 7 6 5
9 8 7 6
```

The starting point for each line is an incrementing number 1 through 9 inclusive, so an outer loop controls that:

```
for (int start = 1; start <= 9; start++) ...
```

*Within* that loop, you count from the starting number down until one of the following conditions is met:

- you reach zero (lines one through four); or
- you reach a number four less than the starting number (lines four through nine).

You'll notice that line four meets *both* those terminating conditions so it's irrelevant which one causes the inner loop to finish. Also note that you don't print anything for the terminating condition.

Hence the inner loop will look like:

```
for (int num = start; (num > 0) && (num > start - 4); num--) ...
```

And, of course, within the inner loop, you need to actually print out the number. Tying it all together, you can achieve the desired output with something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    // Lines from 1 to 9 inclusive.

    for (int start = 1; start <= 9; start++) {
        // Output from start to start-3 inclusive,
        //   stopping early if you hit zero.

        for (int num = start; (num > 0) && (num > start - 4); num--) {
            std::cout << num << ' ';
        }

        // Move to next line.

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want

```
using namespace std;
int
main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = i+1; j >0;j-- ){
            if (count >3) break;
            cout << j <<" ";
            count++;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see two problems here you may want to fix. The first is including `iostream` - unless you're providing a small snippet, it usually better to post fully functional programs. Second, is the terminating condition for the outer loop - the way you have it, the final line is `10 9 8 7` rather than `9 8 7 6`. You can fix that by changing it to `for(int i = 0; i < 9; i ++){`.

Answer (score 1):

My five cents.:)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 4;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i <= 9; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N && i - j != 0; j++ ) std::cout << i - j << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 
2 1 
3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 
6 5 4 3 
7 6 5 4 
8 7 6 5 
9 8 7 6
```